# What is the best way to do load test Emails

Tags: email, load-testing

our application SLA is to send 25000 emails per hour. We use AWS SES, So use success simulate email provided by AWS SES as in here instead of sending actual emails

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html

Do we have any best way to do load test other than this

Comment: This is not really a programming question within the scope of Stackoverflow. You may find that sqa.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I was not aware that we have separate one. I will post there